# bind click to element added in dom, cause trigger element to perform

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm binding a element with a click function when its added to the dom. My issue here is that if i add lets say 3 elements, and i click any of those it performs that function 3 times. what is it that makes it trigger those 3 times and could this be done any other way?

let me illustrate it with a jsfiddle [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pcy2E/1/)

html

```
<div id="breadcrumb"><a href="#" id="start" class="click-me">Start</a></div>
<a href="#" id="add_to_breadcrumb">Add to breadcrumb</a>​
```

jquery

```
$('#add_to_breadcrumb').on('click', function(){
    $('#breadcrumb').append('<a href="#" class="click-me">' + $('#breadcrumb > a').size() + '</a>', bindClick());


});

function bindClick(){
    $(document).on('click', '.click-me', function(){
        alert($(this).text());        
    });        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$('#add_to_breadcrumb').on('click', function() {
    $('#breadcrumb').append('<a href="#" class="click-me">' + $('#breadcrumb > a').size() + '</a>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.click-me', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/Pcy2E/2/)**

Binding `click` event on each append, cause bind to each element again and again with each append.